# AWS - Log aggregation and visualization

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

We have couple of application running on AWS. Currently we are redirecting all our logs to single bucket. However for ease of access to users, I am thinking to install ELK Stack on EC2 instance.

Would want to check if there is alternate way available where I don't have to maintain this stack.

Scaling won't be an issue, as this is only for logs generated through application running on AWS, so not ingestion or processing is required. mostly log4j logs.

Comment: No sure what do you mean by "better"? Cheaper, easier to setup, faster? Nevertheless, if you have logs in CloudWatch Logs than you can subscribe your log group(s) to ES domain . Automatically and in real-time all new logs will be available in ES for analysis and visualization using Kibana.

Answer (score 0):

You can go for either the managed Elasticsearch available in AWS or setup your own in an EC2 instance

It usually comes down to the price involved and the amount of time you have in hand in setting up and maintaining your own setup

With your own setup, you can do a lot more configurations than that provided by the managed service and also helps in reducing the cost

You can find more info on this [blog](https://sematext.com/blog/self-hosted-vs-aws-elasticsearch/)